# Restaurar Base de datos Inexistente

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera restaurar una base de datos completa en mi instancia que no tengo agregada previamente o no tengo registro alguno. 
Ejemplo: 
Yo tengo en mi Sql :
Db A.bak
Db B.bak
Db C.bak

y en una localicacion de mi Pc tengo Db D, pero al momento de restaurar me sale un error de que no encuentra la base de datos en mi instancia o sistema (Sql), hay forma de restaurarla o que me creé esa nueva Base de Datos a partir de ese Backup.
Como codigo tengo el común: `Restore Database [Db D] From Disk='Ruta Archivo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que la base de datos no existe, además de indicar el nombre del archivo de copia de seguridad, debes indicar dónde colocar los archivos de datos.

Para ello, debes conocer el *nombre* de estos archivos en la copia de seguridad y completar tu sentencia con las opciones `with` correspondientes, por ejemplo:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [MiNuevaDB] 
  FROM  DISK = N'C:\bak\MiBackup.bak' 
  WITH     MOVE N'Datos' TO N'C:\Datos\MSSQL12.SERVER\MiNuevaDB.mdf'
        ,  MOVE N'Log' TO N'C:\Datos\MSSQL12.SERVER\MiNuevaDB.ldf'
        ,  NOUNLOAD
        ,  STATS = 5

GO
```

Si no sabes el nombre de los archivos y tienes el Management Studio instalado, puedes utilizarlo para generar el comando correcto para restaurar.

Con clic derecho en *databases* selecciona la opción *Restore database*
[image: Menú contextual]

Seleccionas el archivo a restaurar, completas la información del diálogo, y das clic en OK.

[image: Diálogo de restaurar backup]

Comment: los datos que colocas dentro de N'DATOS, N'Log son genéricos? es decir... siempre serán los mismos datos variando obviamente el nombre de la DB?

Comment: Son personalizados y dependerán de donde deseas colocar la base de datos. Siempre hay al menos un archivo de datos (.mdf) y uno de log (.ldf), pero puede haber más archivos de datos (.ndf).

Comment: @Marcela, Los nombres dependen de cada base de datos, se definen cuando se van creando los archivos de datos. Si has utilizado el Management Studio para crearlas, generalmente se llaman `xxx`  y `xxx_log`, dónde `xxx` es el nombre de la base de datos. Si no la creaste tu, pregúntale a la persona que la creó.